# How to produce a printable PGP detached signature (eventually in base16)?

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

Given a detached signature `mydoc.sig` of a document `mydoc` produced with

```
gpg --local-user <GPG_RECIPIENT> --detach-sig mydoc
```

**How can I create a printable output of this signature in base16 (as when exporting a private key with `paperkey`)?**

The ASCII armor signature is a convenient output to be printed,

Obviously the following is not working

```
  cat mydoc.sig | paperkey
  Unable to find secret key packet
```

I am looking for a output like the one below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
od -t x1 mydoc.sig
```

produces similar output that should be just as usable.

As you presumably know since you mention it in your question, you can also create an ASCII-armored signature using

```
gpg --detach-sig -a mydoc
```

I don’t know whether you’d consider that good enough for printing as-is though. There’s not much point piping *that* through `od`, it will include a CRC but it will also be quite a bit longer than the piped binary signature.